# Inverter posições de Divs com responsivo

Tags: html, css

```css
.a-right {
    padding: 2%;
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
}

.a-center {
    padding: 2%;
    width: 50%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    .a-center {width: 85%}
    .a-right {float: none; width: 95%}
    body{
        float: none;
    }
 
 #globo{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
 }
 
 ul.topnav li a.active {margin-left: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a-right">
  <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
  
  <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
</div>

<div class="a-center">
    <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
  
  <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
</div>
```

Tem como eu inverter as posições das Divs quando o site é acessado pelo celular?

Comment: Da esquerda pra direita ou da direita jogar pra baixo?

Comment: tipo, do jeito que está, fica uma div na esquerda, e a outra na direita, quando eu entro pelo celular nela, fica uma em baixo da outra, na ordem 

<div class="a-right">
e em baixo
<div class="a-center">

eu queria que invertesse isso, a div "a-center" ficasse em cima da "a-right".

Desculpe, realmente não fui bem claro..

Comment: Fabio se inverter as ordens e aplicar float ao a-center deve funcionar, testa isto por favor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/243714/3635

Answer (score 1):

O seu CSS está perfeito, basta inverter a ordem das DIVs, também será necessário adicionar `float: left;` para o a-center e remove-lo no media-query (`@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`):

```css
.a-right {
    padding: 2%;
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
}

.a-center {
    padding: 2%;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    .a-center {float: none; width: 85%}
    .a-right {float: none; width: 95%}
    body{
        float: none;
    }
 
 #globo{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
 }
 
 ul.topnav li a.active {margin-left: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a-center">
    <p>a-center</p>
    <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
  
  <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
</div>

<div class="a-right">
    <p>a-right</p>
  <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
  
  <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou certinho amigo, mas tem um porém, eu tenho um footer lá em baixo, e como as duas divs estão flutuando, o meu footer ficou bagunçado entre elas, sabe como eu resolvo?

Comment: Consegui resolver, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fabio A minha resposta deu certo? Se sim poderia marcar como correta?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é colocando as `divs` dentro de um `.container` e aplicando `display: table;`. Desta forma, você poderá reordenar a posição das `divs` dentro do `@media` definindo o que fica em cima (`table-header-group;`) e o que fica embaixo (`table-footer-group;` ou `table-row-group;`):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="a-right">
      <p>1. You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>

      <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
    </div>

    <div class="a-center">
        <p>2. You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>

      <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
   display:table;    
}
.a-right {
    display:table-footer-group;
}
.a-center {
    display:table-header-group;
}
```

```css
.a-right {
    padding: 2%;
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
}

.a-center {
    padding: 2%;
    width: 50%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    .a-center {width: 85%}
    .a-right {float: none; width: 95%}
    body{
        float: none;
    }
 
 #globo{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
 }
 
 ul.topnav li a.active {margin-left: 0;}

 .container {
    display:table;    
 }
 .a-right {
  display:table-footer-group;
 }
 .a-center {
  display:table-header-group;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="a-right">
      <p>1. You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
      
      <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="a-center">
        <p>2. You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
      
      <p>You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states. For instance, the following rule will apply its styles if the user's device has either a minimum height of 680px or is a screen device in portrait mode:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é a propriedade `order` das [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)...

```css
.a-right {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}

.a-center {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 50%;
 margin-left: 5%;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .a-center {width: 85%; text-align: center}
    .a-right {width: 95%; text-align: center}
    body{
        float: none;
    }
    .ctn{
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
    }
    .a-right {
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
          -ms-flex-order: 2;
              order: 2;
    }
    .a-center {
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
          -ms-flex-order: 1;
              order: 1;
    }
}
.ctn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctn">
<div class="a-right">
  <p>texto....</p>
  
  <p>Order 1</p>
</div>

<div class="a-center">
    <p>Texto...</p>
  
  <p>Order 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Consulte o [suporte aos navegadores](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)